# About refreshDatabase trait in laravel unit testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, in-memory-database

I've my migrations at two different default location (database/migrations/tables/) and (database/migrations/foreign/)  and i want to use the RefreshDatabase trait, however it uses the default migration location.

How can i specify or override at setUp or somewhere the "path" option for this migrations?

The only way that i found to do that is overriding "refreshInMemoryDatabase" and "refreshTestDatabase" methods but im thinking in a better way.
Can anyone help me in this trick!

Answer (score 0):

Override the `refreshTestDatabase` method of `RefreshDatabase` trait by specifying `--path=/app/database/migrations/tests`. It will be the best way

```php
protected function refreshTestDatabase()
{
    if (! RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated) {
        $this->artisan(
            'migrate:fresh --path=/app/database/migrations/tests',
            $this->migrateFreshUsing()
        );

        $this->app[Kernel::class]->setArtisan(null);

        RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated = true;
    }

    $this->beginDatabaseTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trait has two methods that are used to provide options to the migrate command:

- `migrateUsing()` when using a sqlite in-memory database
- `migrateFreshUsing()` when not using a sqlite in-memory database

As an example, if using a sqlite in-memory database, you could do this:

```
/**
 * The parameters that should be used when running "migrate".
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function migrateUsing()
{
    return [
        '--seed' => $this->shouldSeed(),
        '--seeder' => $this->seeder(),
        '--path' => 'database/migrations/tables',
        '--path' => 'database/migrations/foreign',
    ];
}
```

Or, if you want to be able to call the original function, you can rename it when using the trait:

```
use RefreshDatabase {
    migrateUsing as traitMigrateUsing;
}

protected function migrateUsing()
{
    // Merge in your new values with the default values.
    return array_merge($this->traitMigrateUsing(), [
        '--path' => 'database/migrations/tables',
        '--path' => 'database/migrations/foreign',
    ]);
}
```

If you're not using an in-memory database, you would need to override the `migrateFreshUsing()` method instead. In this case, the default logic is slightly more complicated, so it would probably be better to call it from the trait. That would look like:

```
use RefreshDatabase {
    migrateFreshUsing as traitMigrateFreshUsing;
}

protected function migrateFreshUsing()
{
    // Merge in your new values with the default values.
    return array_merge($this->traitMigrateFreshUsing(), [
        '--path' => 'database/migrations/tables',
        '--path' => 'database/migrations/foreign',
    ]);
}
```